# Pod install not updating pods in XCWorkspace

Tags: ios, cocoapods

My podfile has:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'CoChat' do
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
#pod 'MobileDeepLinking-iOS'
end
```

I run pod install and get:

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (3.0.4)
Using Bolts (1.6.0)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.10.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.10.0)
Using FBSDKShareKit (4.10.0)
Using Firebase (2.5.1)
Installing FirebaseUI (0.3.2)
Installing Google (1.3.2)
Installing GoogleAppUtilities (1.0.0)
Installing GoogleAuthUtilities (1.0.1)
Installing GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.1.0)
Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.0.0)
Installing GoogleSignIn (2.4.0)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.0.3)
Installing GoogleUtilities (1.1.0)
[!] The 'Pods-CoChat' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/Nathan/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Desktop/CoChat/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a and /Users/Nathan/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Desktop/CoChat/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLSignIn.a)
```

When you open the XCWorkspace, nothing has changed. The FirebaseUI pod/framework is not there. Not a clue why this isn't installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem. The problem is with FirebaseUI/Auth and Google Sign in.

Solution

1. comment out use_frameworks!
2. Use bridging headers files by creating
   a cocoa touch file, remember to check the box for 'Create a bridging
   header file' and then after creation only deleting the .m .h files
   as you want the bridging header file. Manually call out the headers
   files from there.

If you read the posts on https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed, some seem to have similar issue. One possible fix is to get the 0.2.6 version of FirebaseUI by including '~>0.2.6' beside the firebaseUI pod

Hope this helps and hopefully this bug is fixed.